Different specializations of class template invokes static member function of each other recursively
The function Dictate<T> is used to collect type informations about T。If there are any orhter types associated with the type T their information is collected also.
The class template type is designed to be specialized by each exact type to provide type specific information and operations.
The static function type<T>::dictate try to fill up TypeDesc with its type specific information. If another type is associated with this T， type<T>::dictate invokes Dictate<T> to attain the type descriptor of the associated type.
The following code could be the smallest example to reproduce the error:
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

/**
 * This is the structure causes recursive template instantiation.
 */
struct TypeDesc {
  std::weak_ptr<TypeDesc const> subtypes;
};

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<TypeDesc const> Dictate();

/**
 * this is the abstract class that will be implemented by each type.
 */
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct type;

/**
 * specialization for std::weak_ptr<T>
 */
template <typename Tp>
struct type<std::weak_ptr<Tp>> {
  static void dictate(TypeDesc& desc) {
    desc.subtypes = {Dictate<Tp>()};
  }
};

/**
 * specialization for TypeDesc
 */
template <>
struct type<TypeDesc> {
  static void dictate(TypeDesc& desc) {
    desc.subtypes = Dictate<decltype(TypeDesc::subtypes)>();
  }
};

/**
 * The entry function of Dictate.
 */
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<TypeDesc const> Dictate() {
  auto desc = std::make_shared<TypeDesc>();
  type<T>::dictate(*desc);

  return desc;
}

/**
 * The main function.
 */
int main() { Dictate<TypeDesc>(); }

The above code causes the compiler produce the following error message:
error: incomplete type ‘type<const TypeDesc, void>’ used in nested name specifier
   47 |   type<T>::dictate(*desc);

Spliting definition and declarations gives no help.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When you have a question about code you best post a [mcve] so others can copy the code and reproduce the error.

its ok to reduce the code, but if you show us stripped down code and an error message from other code, then we cannot help. Post the code that produces the error and the error message, then we can help

We want one single piece of code that we can (try to) compile and see the same error as you do; reduced as much as possible to remove irrelevant code.

This doesn't look like a [mcve]

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you're definitely right, I'm extracting necessary code, minimal reproducible example coming soom .

There's more than one source files to be used, the fastest way to share them that I could come up with is to put them onto github, and so am I did. Thank you for saving my day ^_^  @463035818_is_not_an_ai

A big thank to you also. I can mention only one person in one comment, so I made this comment to let you know I'm grateful to you also. @user12002570

sorry, but a github will not save your day. The [mcve] should be in the question.

most compiler errors (ie not linker errors) are reproducible with a single source file

don't expect others to download a repo to read the question. Keep in mind that the question is supposed to be also for future readers with the same problem, thats one reason why you should phrase the question such that a reader can immediately see the issue without needing to go through a long process of downloading files

This is still too much code. Please try to reduce it into a single snippet that fits into your question as text (let's say ~50 lines; I doubt the underlying problem is so complex that it can't be represented in this number of lines). Try to construct the simplest possible example that reproduces the problem, remove everything else.

Well, let me have a try to reduce code into a similar example to produce the same problem.

Hey, I'm not sure if you are notified when I make the question edited, so I made this comment and mention you to let you know that I've tried to make a smallest code example and posted it to the question. @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Hey, I'm not sure if you are notified when I make the question edited, so I made this comment and mention you to let you know that I've tried to make a smallest code example and posted it to the question. @HolyBlackCat

No, we don't get notified on edits, so it's good that you ping us in comments.

looks good https://godbolt.org/z/db8z18vfs. You should now clean up the question. We need not see some error from other code, some code fragments and only in the end the code that matters. I suggest to remove most if not all and only keep the minimal example at the end and include the compiler error message it produces. Fwiw, if someone wants to see the edit history of the question they can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78407058/revisions. You do not need to keep the old stuff around nor do you need to mark edits with "Edit" or similar.

Yep, this example is better. You do Dictate<decltype(TypeDesc::subtypes)>, which becomes Dictate<std::weak_ptr<TypeDesc const>. It then calls type<std::weak_ptr<Tp>>::name(), with Tp == TypeDesc const. It then tries to use type<TypeDesc const>, but there's no such specialization. You're just missing std::remove_const_t.

What a big joke I made >_< Thank you so much ! You really saved my day. Could you please answer this question ? And I'll accept it. @HolyBlackCat

One more question confusing me. As you already know, there are so many code around this work, where do you think is the best place to strip the type expression to make sure the code expresses what I mean ? @HolyBlackCat

You're right, the kernel of this problem is as simple as the final code fragment shows which is about the language. But there's another question confusing me that I'm not sure where is the best place to filter out the const modifiers. That's a problem about engineering. I think the second problem may be the reason why I could not notice the reason of the first problem. I've no idea, what do you think ? @463035818_is_not_an_ai

@王雨泽 Nah, I don't think this needs a full answer. You can post one if you want to. "best place to strip the type expression" I'd make something like template <typename T> using something = type<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;, and use it instead of type everywhere.

Brilliant move, I'll try. @HolyBlackCat

std::weak_ptr p = std::make_shared<T>(); is mostly pointless. refcount would be 0.

You're right, but don't worry. There was a map contains those shared pointers created by the function Dictate, which is filtered out to simplify the code. @Jarod42
